# JSF Primefaces two editable data tables in a form

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I am having two editable primefaces data tables in a form.

This is the edit and cancel event handlers in first data table.

```
<p:ajax event="rowEdit" listener="#{myBean.onEdit1}" update=":myForm:messages" />
<p:ajax event="rowEditCancel" listener="#{myBean.onCancel1}" update=":myForm:messages" />
```

And this is the edit and cancel event handlers in second data table.

```
<p:ajax event="rowEdit" listener="#{myBean.onEdit2}" update=":myForm:messages" />
<p:ajax event="rowEditCancel" listener="#{myBean.onCancel2}" update=":myForm:messages" />
```

But these event handlers are not working as expected. Even if I edit the first table row, its calling second table's event handlers.

Do you know the reason for this?

Comment: were you able to solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

I have no knowledge on custom event names. But I think this is because you have the same event name for both tables. You have replaced/modified `rowEdit` event with second table. Like other languages, only your latest modification will count. 
Did you know there is `<p:inplace>`? I suggest you to use this for editable data.

```
<h:outputText value="Ajax Inplace Editor: " />  
<p:inplace id="ajaxInplace" editor="true">  
            <p:inputText value="#{inplaceBean.text}"  
                        required="true" label="text"/>  
        </p:inplace>
```

Comment: But these event handlers are within the corresponding tables. So it should work for each table edits right?

Comment: Not sure, since I never touch in the area of custom event names. Why don't you try to rename it and see what happens.